# How can I make the ripple effect look like a circle instead of an oval?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, rippledrawable

I have the same ripple effect on most of my image buttons and on most of them it looks like a circle when pressed but on some buttons it looks like an oval and I'm just not sure why it looks different. I realize the actual ripple shape is set as oval but why does it look like a circle on some other buttons. It could be that I am just not seeing it right since it happens so quickly.

Here is my ripple xml:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Turned out to be an issue with me using `layout_weight` on the `ImageButtons` inside a `LinearLayout`. I removed the weight from the individual buttons and instead added spaces with a weight of one between each button like this:

```
 <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . I too had the same issues. The effect is purely dependent on the dimension of the object. for eg a 512*512 image gave me perfect circled ripple effect and a rectangular button on the bottom of the screen gave me oval/ellipsed effect. so i added a small square button behind that rectangular button and added effect to that  squared button. when that button is pressed  i call that square button to show up the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had kind of assumed it worked the way you describe it but the buttons that get an oval ripple have a height and width of 48dp, so they are square. The image inside them is a circle though, not sure how that might affect things.

Comment: I have given my experience based on the issue i faced with rectangular buttons, if the issue is still there with a square button then something is wrong with either the code or the way the ripple is implemented.

Comment: I think I know now why it is happening. I have a `      android:layout_weight="25"` and 4 buttons. So the actual width is much larger than 48dp. I'm going to change it some other layout and I bet that will fix it.

Comment: Yeap, it was the layout weight. I'll mark you as correct since you explained how it works.